# Getting the index position from an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Prerequisites: has to be single dimension arrays and it can't be HashMaps or ArrayLists

Preface:

I am currently stuck and have been stuck for quite some time now. I really need some assistance or different thought process right now. So I have two arrays that both contain strings. The function of the program is to take user input, check to see if it exists in one array and output the same exact index position of second array in respect to the first array. For example if the user types a word that exists as array1[5] it should output the word located at array2[5]. I am currently to the point where my program can accurately determine whether or not the user input matches a string in my first array.

Problem:

So the part i'm stuck on is getting the index integer value from the first array and getting it to use the same integer value to draw the same position in the second array. In general terms I need to know how to store the value of x in array1[x] and store it as a variable and print out array2[x] and basically have them match.

```
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ){
  Object obj = ae.getSource();

  if ( obj == b1)
   {
    input = tf1.getText();

    for (e=0; e<english.length; e++)
    {
         if (!input.equals(english[e]))
          {
           translate = false;

          }

          else if (input.equals(english[e]))
          {
           output = swedish[index];

           translate = true;
           repaint();
           break;


      }

    }


    }
```

Comment: What is `index` supposed to be?

Comment: index was an attempt at storing the position of english[e] but didn't work out. So as of right now its nothing

Comment: Forgive me if it's me being daft, but is `e` not the index you need here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the second array via `swedish[index]`however there is no `index` variable anywhere in your code. I think it should be `swedish[e]`.

This way you are using the exact same index to access the second array, when you have a match in the first array.

Comment: so.. i'm pretty tired and I swear to god I tried that earlier today and it didn't work but i does now. Thank you

Comment: i'm just going to delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Just have an output String, then as you're looping through the English array

if input.equals(english[e]) output = swedish[e]

Answer (score 0):

after

```
for (e=0; e<english.length; e++)
    {
```

put index=e;

Answer (score 0):

I am sort of confused on your question but I will try to answer it.

array_1 = first array

array_2 = second array

1. If you are trying to print the String in array_2 based on the matching index location from array_1
   Just change

   `output = swedish[index];`

   with

   `output = swedish[e];`
2. If you are trying to store the position index of the matching string from array_1 in one variable and then use it to print whatever is stored in that location in array_2. Then;

   store the value of e in an int.

   `int matchingLocation = e;`

   Then use it do what you want, for example print whatever is in array_2 at such location

   `System.out.println(array_2[matchingLocation]);`